# Compute the number of Inversions

Tags: algorithm, code-complexity

Let `A[1...n]` be an array consisting of n different numbers.

The pair `(i, j)` is called an *inverse*, If `i < j and A [i] > A [j]`.

**Example:**

A := (2, 3, 8, 6, 1) => A has 5 inverses.

**Task:**

Write program to find the number of inverses of the array A [1..n] such that the complexity of the algorithm is O (n * logn).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Homework questions should show effort and the current code that you have. You are unlikely to get a good response by dumping your homework question verbatim; explain what you're struggling with and provide clear debugging information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40001355/1040597

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved based on the merge sort.

strictly speaking, you should modify the procedure `merge(A, B)` that it returns the number of pairs `(a, b)  such that a in A, b in B and b > c`.

As you can see the run time that is required to solve this problem is the run time of the merge sort, hence `O(n * log(n))`

Comment: Could you post your code that I can guide you through the path to the solution